# Deploying Java war files on AZURE

Tags: azure, web-deployment

I am deploying my website using Git. I executed all the commands mentioned above, but my WAR file is getting copied into wwwroot folder, rather than webapps folder. Apart from the commands mentioned above, do we need to mention to which folder on azure do we need to transfer our files? Am I missing something here? Could anyone please help me how to transfer them into web apps folder